# File searching in a directory using php

Tags: php, file, search

How i can list all the  files in a folder and its sub folders using php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of the SPL iterators. In particular the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` which will recursively traverse through a given directory structure.

Like so:

```
$realpath = realpath('/path/to/file');


$fileObjects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($realpath),
                 RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($fileObjects as $key => $object){
    if($object->getFilename() === 'filename.png') {
        echo $object->getPathname();
    }
}
```

The `SELF_FIRST` iteration mode basically tells the iterator that the parent items are to be placed first (parents come first).

Comment: `SELF_FIRST` isn't particularly useful for listing files only and may confuse the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about for a php script running as its own program or a web application.  Why would you need to do this?

```
echo shell_exec('find -name *');
```

But then you can really just run that in the shell.

If you want a web application to run this, www-data will need permissions to run that script and it is highly unsafe to let it do that.  Instead you can have a user with appropriate permission log in and do that.  Not quite as unsafe.

Comment: I want to search a particular file in a folder and its sub folder when i am running a web page.

Comment: What do you need to search this file for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script to get all files in a folder(and subfolders) using php [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) in an array. Then you can search that array for your particular file.

**Example:**

```
<?php
    $dir    = '/tmp';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    print_r($files); 
?>
```

**Output something like this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => foo.txt
    [4] => somedir
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to specify a mask or something, like *.txt for all txt files then there is no better function than "[glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)" :)