# how to return a status from functions in php

Tags: php

I am new to OOPHP. Right now I'm writing a search algorithm to search a file name in folders and subfolders. That is working fine for now. But after searching it should display result if filename exists and if its not it should throw a message like "File not found". To achieve this functionality i tried in different ways of updating status variable when function is called. But the scope of variable is not passing in global.Please find the below code for reference(i removed status variable here to avoid confusion).Let me know how can i achieve this by changing code..

```
    function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext) 
    {
        $strsear=$_POST["stringsearch"];

        $globFiles = glob("$dir".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."$strsear*.$ext");
        $globDirs  = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

        foreach ($globDirs as $dir) 
        {
           recursiveGlob($dir, $ext);

        }

        foreach ($globFiles as $file) 
        {
            print "$file";      
        }
     }
```

Comment: check the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895918/file-searching-in-a-directory-using-php

Comment: Btw. Why you don't use ready tool for that? This is quite a good: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext) {
$strsear=$_POST["stringsearch"];
$globFiles = glob("$dir".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."$strsear*.$ext");
$globDirs  = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {
    recursiveGlob($dir, $ext);
}
foreach ($globFiles as $file=>$v) {
     echo $v;
    if(count($v)!=0)$status=1;
}
 $GLOBALS['status']=$status;}
```

Comment: finally we can check with if(is_null($status)){
echo "Sorry. No matches found.";
}

Answer (score 1):

```
   function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext) 
{
    $strsear=$_POST["stringsearch"];

    $globFiles = glob("$dir".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."$strsear*.$ext");
    $globDirs  = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    foreach ($globDirs as $dir) 
    {
       recursiveGlob($dir, $ext);

    }

    foreach ($globFiles as $file) 
    {
        return $file;      
    }
 }



     $string=recursiveGlob($dir, $ext) 
     if(empty($string))s
     print "File Not Found";
     else
     print "File Found".$string;
```

Small Change:

```
foreach ($globFiles as $file=>$v) {

 print "$v"; 
return $v; 

}
```

}

```
 if(!empty($v))
 print "File Found";
 else
 print "File Not Found";
```